# JSON.parse won't parse array?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Here's a code snippet that's been throwing me for a loop:

```
var _tids = [];
console.log("type:", typeof user._imported_readTids, "value:", user._imported_readTids);
try {
    _tids = JSON.parse(user._imported_readTids);
} catch(e) {
    return nxt();
}

console.log("user:", user.uid, "type:", typeof _tids, "\narray:", _tids);
```

in the first `console.log`, the type of the field _imported_readTids is a string, which is expected (a string representation of an array, like `"[1,2,3]"` (no spaces between elements))

When I call JSON.parse on that string, I'm expecting it to be turned into an array, but on the second `console.log`, the type is still a string, and the array representation looks the same.

Here's the output:

```
// first console.log (truncated for brevity):
type: string value: "[4,5,6,7,8,...,234]"

// second: 
user: 1 type: string 
array: [4,5,6,7,8,...,234]
```

I've tried these same params and used in a console nodejs process, and it comes out as expected, `typeof jsonArray` will return `'object'`.

This is in NodeJS, v0.12.5, OSX 10.11.1 (El capitan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time you console.log it says that the string value starts and end with a `"`.

The second time, it does not say that.

You have a string representation of a JSON text which itself consists of a string representation of a JSON text which is an array.

After you parse it, you have a string representation of a JSON text which is an array.

i.e. Your array is **double** stringified, so you need to parse it twice (or fix whatever is encoding it in the first place so it only does it once).

Comment: Now you mention it, it's so obvious...
@OP: The console doesn't show quotes around strings when using `console.log`. Try it: `console.log("foo"); console.log('"foo"');`

Comment: Damn, you're right. Thanks for that lightning fast response!

Answer (score -1):

If you make this change on the php side, it will be solved.

Example:

```
$x=[a,b,x];
$x2=array();

$x2[]=$x;

echo json_encode($x2);
```